# RethinkDB atomic upsert

Tags: rethinkdb

How can I perform an atomic upsert in RethinkDB? For example, a table with urls (id) and count of clicks (count). According to the documentation I should use {conflict: 'update'}, so I tried the following:

```
r.db('test').table('urls').insert({
  id: 'google.com',
  count: r.row('count').add(1).default(1),
  // ... lots of other fields ...
}, {
  conflict: 'update' 
});
```

This returns the error `r.row is not defined in this context`. I saw an issue in their github repo where danielmewes suggested `.get(...).replace(...)` in order to achieve this, but wouldn't it be expensive to replace the whole document to update a field? I could use `get` followed by an `update` or `insert` if it doesn't exist, but this could lead to a race condition since there will be multiple processes writing to this table. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the way to do this is with a `replace` that handles the case where the document doesn't exist.  RethinkDB always rewrites the entire document when you update a field right now, so you shouldn't worry about `replace` having worse performance for that reason.